# Remove duplicates in vector to next value

Tags: r

I have a vector consisting of integers which can take a finite number of values. Consider the case where the values is 0,1,2.

```
a<-c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2)
```

I want to delete replicates of values until the next differnet value. After doing this the result show be

```
0 1 0 2
```

Hence I want to do something like unique (which would have given 0,1,2) but i want to take the ordering into account.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (assuming no `NA`s):

```
a[c(1, diff(a)) != 0]
```

Comment: Any chance then of marking this one as the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Use my favorite tool:

```
Rgames> rle(a<-c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 3 2 2 3
  values : num [1:4] 0 1 0 2
```

Comment: Very good. This was exactly what I needed since I also wanted the indices where the values changed... :)

Comment: @jaclea - if you wish, you can change which answer you accept.