# Removing duplicates in vector but preserving order

Tags: r, vector

Suppose a vector :

```
vec = c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0,NA,0)
```

I would like to get :

```
vec = c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA)
```

I have tried a for loop with an if checking if the value is equal to the previous non NA, but it doesn't work when it is repeated more than once.

[Remove duplicates in vector to next value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997907/remove-duplicates-in-vector-to-next-value)
doesn't work either since I want to keep my NAs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `duplicated`:

```
vec[duplicated(vec, incomparables=NA)] <- NA
```

You could omit the `incomparables` parameter in your example:

```
vec[duplicated(vec)] <- NA
```

According to the documentation this might be faster, but you'd need to benchmark it yourself.

**Edit:**

After clarification:

```
vec <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0,NA,0)
vec2 <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA)

tmp <- vec[!is.na(vec)]
tmp[c(FALSE, diff(tmp)==0)] <- NA
vec[!is.na(vec)] <- tmp

identical(vec, vec2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't more clear but the vector doesn't stop there, there could be 1s following. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a little bit of logic and a compound `[` and `[<-` operation. First we need to find the duplicates. We'll do this with `diff()` on all the non `NA` values...

```
diff( vec[ ! is.na( vec ) ]
[1]  0 -1  0  0  1  0 -1  0
```

Each `0` is a duplicate. Now we need to find their position in `vec` and set them to `NA`..

```
#  This gives us a vector of TRUE/FALSE values which we will use to subset vec to the values we want to change
dups <- c( 1 , diff( vec[ ! is.na( vec ) ] ) ) == 0

#  Now subset vec to non NA values and change the duplicates to NA
vec[ ! is.na( vec ) ][ dups ] <- NA
# [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA
#[26] NA NA  0 NA NA
```

Comment: i desperatly lack the logic with vector manipulation in R,thanks for explaining it.

Comment: Might be more confusing, but you can essentially do this via `rle` . Do `diff(rle(vec)$values[!is.na(rle(vec)$values)]`  and then replace those `0` values with `NA` and run `inverse.rle` on the result.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's clever. I looked at `rle` but I couldn't work it out. You could add an alternative solution?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon see posted answer. Look OK?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft aye +1. I see why I couldn't work it out though! Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

I think this does it:

```
vrl<-rle(vec)
diff(vrl$values[!is.na(vrl$values)])->vdif
vdif<-c(1,vdif)
vrl$values[!is.na(vrl$values)][vdif==0]<-NA
inverse.rle(vrl)
# [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#[19]  1 NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA
```

The trick in there was to prepend a `1` to the difference vector so that the very first non-NA location is preserved.